# Setting value for title of NSOpenPanel does not work

Tags: swift

I want to set title for my NSOpenPanel, but it does not work! Apple says:

> Gets and sets the title for the panel shown at the top of the window.

But I can not make codes works, not sure what is wrong?

```
let nsOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    nsOpenPanel.canChooseFiles = true
    nsOpenPanel.title = "Hello, Choose Files"

   if (nsOpenPanel.runModal() == .OK) ... // rest of codes ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `title` is something from the past when windows in macOS had title bars. To show text or an instruction on top of the NSOpenPanel object, use the `message` property:

```
nsOpenPanel.message = "Hello, Choose Files"
```